# Series expansion of a density function

Tags: probability, mixture-distribution, density-function

Here's something I've wondered about for a while, but haven't been able to discover the correct terminology. Say you have a relatively complicated density function that you suspect might have a close approximation as a sum of (properly weighted) simpler density functions. Have such things been studied? I'm particularly interested in reading about any applications.

Here's one example I've found:

[Expansion of probability density functions as a sum of gamma densities with applications in risk theory](http://www.soa.org/library/research/transactions-of-society-of-actuaries/1966/january/tsa66v18pt1n5211.pdf)

Comment: You could also look into the [saddlepoint approximation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/how-does-saddlepoint-approximation-work/191781#191781).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use Edgeworth series, if your random variable has a finite mean and variance, which expands the CDF of your random variable in terms of the Gaussian CDF.  At first glance it's not quite as tidy conceptually as using a mixture model, but the derivation is quite pretty and it gives you a closed form with very fast decay in the tail terms.

Answer (score 4):

**Histogram density estimator** is estimating the density with a sum of **piecewise functions** (density of a uniform).

**KDE** is using a sum of **smooth function** (gaussian  is an example) (as long as they are positive they can be transformed into a density by normalization)

The use of "**mixture**" in statistic is about convex combination of densities.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with **mixture modeling**. There are a number of R packages on CRAN for doing this. Search for "mixture" at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/