# Asymptotic distribution of a weighted sum of chi squared variables beyond CLT?

Tags: central-limit-theorem, asymptotics, approximation, saddlepoint-approximation

I have a sum
$$ S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} d_i X_i^2, $$
where $X_i$ are independent standard normals, and $d_i > 0$ are fixed real numbers, for example $d_i = i$. The asymptotic distribution of this sum is given by the central limit theorem as $\mathrm{N}(\sum d_i, 2\sum d_i^2)$, and according to the [Berry-Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem), this approximation has error on the order $n^{-1/2}$.

When $n$ is not large enough that I can ignore terms $O(n^{-1/2})$, is there a way to derive a more accurate asymptotic distribution in a tractable closed form, such that the error would be $O(n^{-1})$ or better? For fixed $n$, the CLT also gives a poor approximation of the tail of the distribution.

Does there exist a "universal" distribution that I could use for $S$ in the general cases (like the normal distribution in the CLT, but with extra accuracy). For example, what if $X_i^2$ are i.i.d. Beta random variables instead?

Comment: Use the saddlepoint aproximation, details are here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/how-does-saddlepoint-approximation-work/191781#191781     and in my answer here is a worked example:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479/general-sum-of-gamma-distributions/137318#137318

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I'm aware of the saddle point method, but I don't quite see how that helps me get a closed form.

Comment: Why do you need a closed form?

Comment: (1) The CLT does not apply when $d_i=i$.  (2) Because squared standard Normals, rescaled, are Gamma distributions, this question is completely answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479.