# What is the probability distribution for the squared distance between random points in an $n$-dimensional hypercube?

Tags: distributions, distance, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, saddlepoint-approximation

I choose random points $X,\,Y$ in $[0,\,1]^n$ (I assume all $2n$ Cartesian coordinates are $U(0,\,1)$ iids). What is the probability distribution of $\left\Vert X-Y\right\Vert _{2}^{2}$? Even the $n=1$ case requires some care, since if I first fix $X$ then $Y$ has a uniform distribution with extrema of opposite sign.

Comment: You ask about the sum of identically distributed independent variables (the $(X_i-Y_i)^2$, whose distribution is readily computed). The methods explained in the investigation at  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43075 will therefore be applicable to solving this problem. As that thread indicates, the result will be messy: to describe it with a formula typically requires $n$ separate expressions. Thus, it would help for you to indicate *in what form* you are looking for an answer as well as to tell us whether approximate solutions would be acceptable in your application, whatever it might be.

Comment: @whuber An approximate CDF will do.

Answer (score 0):

For an approximate cdf, one possibility is the saddlepoint approximation. For that the mgf (moment generating function), or its logarithm, the cgf (cumulant generating function) is needed. For background see [How does saddlepoint approximation work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191492/how-does-saddlepoint-approximation-work/191781#191781).   So let $X_1, \dotsc, X_n, Y_1, \dotsc, Y_n$ be iid $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$. Then $D^2 = \sum_i (X_i-Y_i)^2$ have mgf
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}  
M_n(t)=M_{\sum_i (X_i-Y_i)^2}(t)=M_{(X_1-Y_1)^2}(t)^n=\left(\E e^{(X_1-Y_1)^2 t}\right)^n
$$ so the cgf is
$$
   K_n(t)=n\cdot \log\left\{ \E e^{(X_1-Y_1)^2 t} \right\}
$$ which in this case is defined for all real $t$.

Without going into details, and with some help from maple, we find that
$$
 \E e^{(X_1-Y_1)^2 t} = {\frac {\sqrt {\pi}{\rm erf} \left(\sqrt {-t}\right){t}^{2}+{{\rm e}^{
t}} \left( -t \right) ^{3/2}- \left( -t \right) ^{3/2}}{ \left( -t
 \right) ^{5/2}}}
$$  or alternatively
$$
 \E e^{(X_1-Y_1)^2 t} = {\frac {-2\,i{{\rm e}^{t}}{\it dawson} \left( i\sqrt {-t} \right) {t}^
{2}+{{\rm e}^{t}} \left( -t \right) ^{3/2}- \left( -t \right) ^{3/2}}{
 \left( -t \right) ^{5/2}}}
$$ but before using this numerically, more work will be needed to find a useful form.

I will come back later to add the resulting approximation.